# Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Configuration.dll'

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a small test build (written in C#) in Visual Studio. However, I get two errors when trying so and can't find the issue. No line's are given:

**Error 1:** *small_project.csproj*

> Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Configuration.dll'

**Error 2:**

> Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Configuration, Version 2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken.. etc..

I am new at developing with C# and XAML. Does someone know what could cause these errors?

Comment: See your references in project.

Comment: @JoséFrancisco There is no System.Configuration.dll there. I guess that I have to look for that?

Comment: @JoséFrancisco So it is not there. How can I add it?

Comment: References ->  (right button) add Reference -> Assemblies -> System.Configuration

Comment: It says: "All of the Framework assemblies are already referenced. Please use Object Browser to explore the references in the Framework". I did that, but System.Configuration does not exist in that list.

Comment: Also have this error now...........

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015: Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=0.0.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106646/visual-studio-2015-type-universe-cannot-resolve-assembly-system-runtime-versi)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old and all, but I am faced with the same error. I've done numerous xaml apps using a variety of test frameworks. I think that you might have made a Universal Windows App using the Unit Test template. Something in the MStest framework that was added was giving me the same exception that you reported here. After lots of looking around I watched a channel 9 video that mentioned them using xUnit for their UWP testing. I went to this site [xUnit on github](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-uwp.html) and did what they mentioned which was:

- remove references to ms test
- open projects.json

  - add xunit 2.1 and xunit.runners.visualstudio 2.1 dependencies
  - fix my unit test to use xUnit instead of MsTest/Nunit
- build
- opened test explorer and ran all tests

I'll have to keep in mind that testing UWP is going to be different than normal apps and so to change my expectations. Hopefully this helps others as well as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when my project's nuget packages weren't available when trying a remote build on Jenkins.

I just added a build-step to locate NuGet and then call `restore` on the project/solution to resolve this for automation purposes.

This is just a segment of a script that I'm copying, so update to your needs:

```
where nuget > nul 2>&1 nul
IF "%errorlevel%"=="0" where nuget > .\where_nuget.txt && Set where_nuget=where_nuget.txt
IF NOT "%where_nuget%"=="" FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I IN ('type where_nuget.txt') DO call "%%I" restore "%Build_Target%"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that my UWP project referenced a project that referenced System.Web.Application.dll. I did:

- Delete reference from the parent project
- Clean and build parent project
- Update Service Reference in child project
- Clean and build child project
- Remove unused reference from child project (System.Web.dll)

I learnt it's better to use nuget packages instead of adding references manually.

[image: System.Web.ApplicationServices-Error]